# Cyrillic characters displayed wrongly when using Montserrat in Bulgarian

Tags: html, localization, webfonts

When using the [Montserrat](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat) font from Google Fonts and setting the HTML language to Bulgarian, some character are displayed wrongly in some browsers.

When using another font (e.g. [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto)) or leaving the browser's native font the text is displayed correctly.

When setting another Cyrillic language (e.g. Russian) the characters are displayed correctly too.

Montserrat claims to support Cyrillic and Extended Cyrillic.

We don't have a copy of Montserrat installed locally.

Including the font using the extended syntax (`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,vietnamese" rel="stylesheet">`) yields no difference.

What's going on?

We can't easily change the font or language due to respectively the customer and the CMS.

Using Bulgarian the characters are displayed incorrectly in Montserrat:

[image]

Using Russian the characters are displayed correctly everywhere:

[image]

We ran the following tests:

- Chrome 71.0.3578.98 on Windows 10 Enterprise 17134.556: has the problem
- Firefox 64.0.2 on Windows 10 Pro 17134.523: has the problem
- Internet Explorer 11.523.17134.0 on Windows 10 Enterprise 17134.556: doesn't have the problem
- Edge 42.17134.1.0 on Windows 10 Enterprise 17134.556: doesn't have the problem
- Chrome 71.0.3578.98 on MacOS 10.13.6: doesn't have the problem

Below you can find a quick example to reproduce the problem.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html id='html' lang='bg'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no' />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,vietnamese" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,greek,greek-ext,latin-ext,vietnamese" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      h1 { font-size: 2em; }
      p { font-size: 1.5em; }
      .native { font-family: sans-serif; }
      .montserrat { font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif; }
      .roboto { font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; }
    </style>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <button id='set-bg' type='button'>Set BG</button>
      <button id='set-ru' type='button'>Set RU</button>
    </p>
    <p>User agent: <code id='user-agent'></code></p>
    <p>Language: <code id='lang'></code></p>
    <h1 class='native'>Native</h1>
    <p class='native'>Научете повече за всички наши продукти</p>
    <p class='native'>Допълващи продукти</p>
    <h1 class='montserrat'>Montserrat</h1>
    <p class='montserrat'>Научете повече за всички наши продукти</p>
    <p class='montserrat'>Допълващи продукти</p>
    <h1 class='roboto'>Roboto</h1>
    <p class='roboto'>Научете повече за всички наши продукти</p>
    <p class='roboto'>Допълващи продукти</p>
    <script>
      (function () {
        'use strict';
        function refreshCurrentLang() {
          document.getElementById('lang').innerText = document.getElementById('html').getAttribute('lang');
        };
        function setTogglerHandler(togglerSelector, langValue) {
          document.getElementById(togglerSelector).addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('html').setAttribute('lang', langValue);
            refreshCurrentLang();
          });
        };
        document.getElementById('user-agent').innerText = navigator.userAgent;
        setTogglerHandler('set-bg', 'bg');
        setTogglerHandler('set-ru', 'ru');
        refreshCurrentLang();
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not incorrect. Bulgaria has relatively recently (late 20th century) developed its own version of the Cyrillic script, and it's slowly starting to become standard, first with Google fonts, and now also with Apple (Bulgarian texts look like this in the iOS 13 system font). It looks unusual and it's quite controversial for other users of Cyrillic, but Bulgarians are quite familiar with these letters already.
[https://bg.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Българска_кирилица](https://bg.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8A%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)

Answer (score 1):

You can force the browser to use the standard cyrillic glyphs using this:

```css
*
{
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "locl" 0;
  -moz-font-feature-settings:    "locl" 0;
  -ms-font-feature-settings:     "locl" 0;
  font-feature-settings:         "locl" 0;
}
```