# Cyrillic letters of Montserrat font from Google Fonts is rendered wrongly on iOS when lang attribute is not "en"

Tags: html, css, cyrillic, google-webfonts

Initial setup:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&amp;display=swap">
```

```css
html {
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif
}
```

Looks bad when `[lang]` is set to `'ru'` or any other value:

```html
<html lang='ru'>
```

[image: кириллические символы]

Looks good when `[lang]` is set to `'en'`:

```html
<html lang='en'>
```

[image: кириллические символы]

Looks good when `[lang]` is not set:

```html
<html>
```

[image: кириллические символы]

This is how it looks with 'font-family: sans-serif':

[image: кириллические символы]

I faced this issue only on my iPhone with iOS 14.0.1 in any web browser (since all browsers on iOS is based on WebKit).

It is not reproduced on Safari 14 on macOS, or any other browser.

---

Similar issue: [Cyrillic characters displayed wrongly when using Montserrat in Bulgarian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54556466/cyrillic-characters-displayed-wrongly-when-using-montserrat-in-bulgarian)

Comment: Long story short, it seems that iOS Safari chooses Bulgarian version of Cyrillic characters instead of the proper one for the Russian language for some reason. Looks like a bug to be worked around.

Comment: https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/2688

Comment: https://github.com/JulietaUla/Montserrat/issues/109

Comment: font-language-override for the standard (only FF as of writing). -- developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-language-override -- More on -webkit-locale at stackoverflow.com/a/77702242/2344083

Answer (score 0):

Try this in CSS

```
* {
  -webkit-locale: auto;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Works for me